# Android System.currentTimeMillis() value is different on firebase database than generated on app logcat

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am submitting a user last seen on Firebase Realtime Database and before setting value at firebase database I am generating a log with timestamp by `System.currentTimeMillis()` but when I compare it with logcat and database timestamp it submits a different timestamp on the server.

Look at the logcat it shows the correct timestamp and it should be on the server too

```
Disconnect with the firebase server 
Offline Time 5:01 pm 1639308715905
```

Firebase Realtime Database Value of Timestamp [image]

```
1639308009264
```

Both Values are different that's how I get wrong last seen of the user

```
1639308715905 - App one 
1639308009264 - Server One
```

The code I am using for log and to set a value on the server.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
   
    FirebaseDatabase DatabaseInstance;
    DatabaseReference infoConnected;
    



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "On Resume Running");        
        DatabaseInstance.goOnline();
        
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "ON STOP CALLING");
        DatabaseInstance.goOffline();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // Single Instance
        infoConnected = DatabaseInstance.getReference(".info/connected"); // To check firebase connection state
        initialiseOnlineStatus();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
        



    
    private void initialiseOnlineStatus() {
        final DatabaseReference Online = DatabaseInstance.getReference("Users/" + userID + "/Online");
        final DatabaseReference lastOnline = DatabaseInstance.getReference("Users/" + userID + "/lastSeen");


        infoConnected.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                if (connected) {
                    Online.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
                    lastOnline.removeValue();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected To Firebase Server ");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect with firebase server ");
                    Online.onDisconnect().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
                    String offlineTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Offline Time " + App_Functions.getLocalDeviceTimestamp(Long.parseLong(offlineTime)) + " " + offlineTime); // Get local device time from milliseconds
                    lastOnline.onDisconnect().setValue(offlineTime);
                    
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }



}
```

**Update:** I noticed that the last timestamp (generated by an app) is uploading not the current one, I really don't understand how my last seen is not updating by the current timestamp. Please check [gist](https://gist.github.com/varun7952/d6475a1b2dfe1b9b964bd829d53405b8) too for the complete code

I also noticed that on the launch of my activity, the firebase function call twice, first with value `boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean. class);` false than true. So with the false value, I am getting the first timestamp which should not update when activity `onStop` calls and when the app calls `onStop` it updates the timestamp which was first created on app launch.

Comment: There’s a little more than 10 minutes between your two example timestamps. Could one of the clocks be running inaccurately?

Comment: @ole My android device create both timestamp as you can see in code above. It's not clock thing, in code above I'm first getting timestamp from device then upload it to the server, and before uploading I'm generating log in Android studio then upload it on server and when i compare server timestamp with logcat, it's shows the difference between both. I don't understand why because I'm uploading same as in logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say thanks to [@argzdev](https://github.com/argzdev) and [@frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) For helping me out at github. The solution i got from Github by @argzdev:

> The reason this doesn't work is because you're trying
> to set a value after you've already disconnected the connection, it's
> bound to cause issues.
>
> What you can do is change the logic of how you store the timestamp.
> Simply store the timestamp BEFORE you sever the connection. There
> shouldn't be any difference in time, even if there was, it would only
> be miniscule.
>
> Relevant code:

```
 @Override
>     protected void onResume() {
>         super.onResume();
>         Log.d(TAG, "On Resume Running");
> 
>         Online.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
>         lastOnline.removeValue();
>         DatabaseInstance.goOnline();
>     }
> 
> @Override
>     protected void onStop() {
>         super.onStop();
>         Log.d(TAG, "ON STOP CALLING");
> 
>         Online.setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
>         lastOnline.setValue("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
>         DatabaseInstance.goOffline();
>     }
>
```

> Then you can simply remove the onDisconnect in your
> ValueEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this in your code:

```
lastOnline.onDisconnect().setValue(offlineTime);
```

This sends a literal value to the server, with the instruction to write that value when it detects that the client has disconnected. The server has no knowledge of the meaning of the value, and can't make any changes to it.

So if a different value is being written on the server than is being logged in the client, the only reason I can think of is that your calling `onDisconnect` (elsewhere?) too with a different value.

Comment: ` lastOnline.onDisconnect().setValue(offlineTime);` I also tried to add suffix to the value to check if value is setting on some other place. I got the suffix value to server but `offlineTime` is changed. I don't understand how? I am also disconnecting and connecting to the server at onPause and `onResume`

Comment: I noticed that last timestamp (generated by app) is uploading not the current one, i really don't understand how my last seen is not updating the current one even i tired `lastOnline.onDisconnect().setValue(System.currentTimeMillis())` directly

Comment: Can you please suggest issue in my code. I created a gist of firebase database you can check https://gist.github.com/varun7952/d6475a1b2dfe1b9b964bd829d53405b8

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be anything more going on there. Since you're passing the value to write directly from your code, the database can't be modifying it. Are you sure that is the value you're looking at though? I noticed you're passing the value as a string, but I'm not sure if in the screenshot in your question that is actually a string.

Comment: Please look at it again, the value i had was long not string,i was testing with long value, you also can reproduce issue by gist i mentioned. I think it's onDisconnect causing this issue which taking last value of System.currentmTimeMillis(), it's not string or long.

Comment: I update the question.I also noticed that on launch of my activity, the firebase function call twice, first with value `boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);` false then true. So with the false value i am getting the first timestamp which should not update when activity `onStop` calls and when app calls `onStop` it update the timestamp which first created on app launch.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can only see what you share in your code, and the initialization of `infoConnected` is not in there. Assuming it is  listening to `.info/connected`, it is indeed expected to change value a few times when the app starts - as the SDK is establishing a connection to the correct server. But this goes back to the last sentence of my answer: "So if a different value is being written on the server than is being logged in the client, the only reason I can think of is that your calling `onDisconnect` (elsewhere?) too with a different value."

Comment: Sorry i post complete firebasae related code in my activity . Please take a look and i don't have any other `onDisconnect` anywhere else

Comment: It's most probably a bug in Firebase. I create a new project with only firebase code and i am still getting same issue. I raised a issue at github too, please see if you can answer https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3248#

Comment: Raising the same problem with the same code there is unlikely to help. If you want to prove that this is a bug in the SDK (which I doubt, given that the server has no way to make up a value like that), simplify the code. For example, how about attaching the `onDisconnect` only once in the top level of `initialiseOnlineStatus`?

Comment: On GitHub you can reproduce the issue with the given code, and also noticed it's not about the time stamp it can be any random digits. With GitHub minimal code you can reproduce the code and I'm not using any other library or anything else which can effect code. I'm Having onDisconnect only once where I'm setting the values

Answer (score -1):

System.currentTimeMillis() will get you the epoch time of your emulator , meaning whatever the emulator or the phone system time it will give it to you

Comment: I know about the `System.currentTimeMillis()` working. You need to read question again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).